# Reading the pointer declaration as an English statement

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following pointer declarations.

```
int *p[10];

int (*q)[10];
```

What is the difference between 1st and second. How to read them in plain English?

Example:

```
int *p; // it will be read as "p is a pointer to an int"

int **p;  // p is a pointer to an integer pointer.
```

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: pointer to pointer

Comment: [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int *p[10]` is an array of `10` pointers to `int`.  `int (*q)[10]` is `1` pointer to an array of 10 `int`s.